# List all corresponding row and column labels for a specific string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How would I generate a list of row and column labels for each cell that matches a specific string?

The row labels are a list of websites, and the column labels are people's names. I would like a formula to pull the list of row and column labels for cells that match my criteria.

For example, the name 'John Smith' and 'google.com' as long as the matching cell contains "X".

Thanks

Comment: Could you attach a sample spreadsheet and the desired output?

Comment: Here's an example spreadsheet with desired output: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iSNxFdoYlTV49skOXInGy3E1BfEEXoVKEkGaTUm1YcI

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(SORT(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:K="X", B1:K1&"×"&A2:A, )), "×"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use custom function.

**Code:**

```
function myFunction(data) {
  var newArr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++){
      Logger.log(data[i][j]);
      if(data[i][j] == 'X'){
        newArr.push([data[i][0], data[0][j]])
      }
    } 
  }
  return newArr;  
}
```

**Calling your custom function to Sheets:**

```
=myFunction(TRANSPOSE(A1:K11))
```

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)